# Spring-xd strange too many open files error

Tags: spring, spring-xd

I upgraded from spring-xd 1.2.1 to 1.3.0, and have both under /opt on my system. After starting xd in single node (but configured to use Zookeeper), I tried to create another stream (e.g. "time  | log"), and spring-xd throws the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/spring-xd-1.2.1.RELEASE/xd/config/modules/modules.yml (Too many open files)
```

I changed ulimit -n 60000, but it didn't solve the problem. The strange thing is why it still points to spring-xd-1.2.1.RELEASE? I have started both xd-singlenode and xd-shell under /opt/spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE

EDIT: add xd-singlenode running process output just to show it's pointing to 1.3.1:

```
/usr/java/default/bin/java -Dspring.application.name=admin 
-Dlogging.config=file:/opt/spring-xd-1.3.0.RELEASE/xd/config//
/xd-singlenode-logback.groovy -Dxd.home=/opt/spring-xd-1.3.0.RELEASE/xd 
-Dspring.config.location=file:/opt/spring-xd-1.3.0.RELEASE/xd/config// 
-Dxd.config.home=file:/opt
/spring-xd-1.3.0.RELEASE/xd/config// 
-Dspring.config.name=servers,application 
-Dxd.module.config.location=file:/opt/spring-xd-1.3.0.RELEASE/xd/config//modules/ 
-Dxd.module.config.name=modules -classpath 
/opt/spring-xd-1.3.0.RELEASE/xd/modules/processor/scripts:/opt/spring-xd
-1.3.0.RELEASE/xd/config:/opt/spring-xd-1.3.0.RELEASE/xd/lib/activation-
...
```

Answer (score 0):

have you updated your environment variables? specifically XD_CONFIG_LOCATION based on the error shown above.

Comment: I don't have the variables set, but based on the output of xd, it looks correct: